# sorting sql query results in various ways depending on data value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-order-by

Given the following results from a sql query:

```
1,
4,
Red,
Blue,
3,
Green,
2,
Yellow,
Magneta,
Rubi
```

The right order I am trying to achieve is:

**Red,Blue,Green, Magneta,Rubi, Yellow, 1, 2, 3, 4**

- Red, Blue and Green must always be at the top and in that order
- Then, the alpha items should follow order asc (M,R,Y)
- Follow by the numeric items in ascending order to ( 1, 2, 3...)

I have been playing around with the following to no avail, so if anybody can point me in the right direction

```
SELECT myCol FROM myTable
ORDER BY
CASE WHEN myCol='Red' then 1
     WHEN myCol='Blue' then 2
     WHEN myCol='Green' then 3 END,
CASE
     WHEN myCol not in ('Red','Blue','Green') and IsNumeric(party_id) = 0 then myCol END ASC,
CASE
     WHEN myCol not in ('Red','Blue','Green') and IsNumeric(party_id) = 1 then CAST(myCol AS INT) END ASC
```

Thanks!

**EDIT 1:**
My current order is actually returning:

```
1,2,3,4, Magneta, Rubi, Yellow, Red, Blue, Green
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Some product specific SQL there...)

Comment: Sorry, I forgot: MicrosoftSQL Server 2014

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this

```
SELECT myCol 
FROM myTable
ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN myCol='Red' THEN 1
        WHEN myCol='Blue' THEN 2
        WHEN myCol='Green' THEN 3 
        ELSE 4
    END,
    CASE
        WHEN myCol NOT IN ('Red','Blue','Green') AND IsNumeric(party_id) = 1 
            THEN CAST(myCol AS INT) 
        ELSE -1 
    END,
    CASE
        WHEN myCol NOT IN ('Red','Blue','Green') AND IsNumeric(party_id) = 0 
            THEN myCol 
    END;
```

Comment: Works like a charm! I would really appreciate some comment as to what is happening in order to fully understand it. Cheers!

Comment: For your question, you could search and see that with `CASE`, in other if you don't set value, then default value will be NULL and SQL Server ORDER NULL First, so you get that wrong result. My query is one way that set the default value for `CASE` so that result will order by your 3 expected groups: RGB, number, and other varchar.